# Nim(rod) not installing to path properly?

Tags: path, ubuntu-14.04, nim-lang

I'm following the [isntructions](http://nim-lang.org/download.html) for installing Nim(rod) onto linux. I then followed [this](http://howistart.org/posts/nim/1) site which showed to do this:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$your_install_dir/bin' >> ~/.profile
$ source ~/.profile
$ nim
```

Typing `nim` in the terminal doesn't do anything.
I have a Nim folder in my home directory with all the files but can't use it.

> I did echo `export PATH=$PATH:$/home/bob/Nim/bin' >> ~/.profile`

And the nim command still does nothing. Am I not doing it right?
The command pwd told me `/home/bob/Nim` when I was in the Nim folder.

I tried running nim with sh in Nim/bin and did `./nim -path:/home/bob/Nim/bin`

and it said:

> config/nim.cfg(45, 2) Hint: added path: '/home/bob/.babel/pkgs/' [Path]
>     config/nim.cfg(46, 2) Hint: added path: '/home/bob/.nimble/pkgs/' [Path]
>     Hint: used config file '/home/bob/Nim/config/nim.cfg' [Conf]

Comment: The bottom line is whether a directory in your `$PATH` contains the `nim` executable. Do any? (`which nim`)

Comment: @itdoesntwork /home/bob/Nim/bin has the nim executable in it.

Comment: Is that the output of `which nim`? I can't think of any reason it could be in your path but still not found by the shell. Restarting the shell might help if this is the case.

Comment: the llatest nim from github

Answer (score 4):

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$/home/bob/Nim/bin' >> ~/.profile
```

You appended the location `$/home/bob/Nim/bin` which doesn't exist. You must remove the `$`.